# How image moves (i.e its velocity) in convex mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Well, I was going through and got stuck on a question that asked me to find the speed of the truck with respect to the earth. The distance between the pole and the object was given, and the image's speed and radius of curvature were given. Also, the speed of the car was given. If you take all that into account, I can use the mirror equation to find the speed.

$$\frac{2}{R}=\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{u}$$

we can rearrange it as:

$$v=\frac{uR}{2u-R}$$

And if we derivative with respect to time we will get the equation for the speed of the image and it turns out to be:

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-R^2\frac{du}{dt}(\frac{1}{(2u-R)^2})$$
Thus the speed of the object with respect to the mirror is
$$\frac{du}{dt}=-\frac{(2u-R)^2}{R^2}\frac{dv}{dt}$$

Thus the speed of the truck with respect to the earth is then:
$$v_{t}=v_{c}+\frac{du}{dt}$$

So I plugged in the values and got some answers. But the answers don't match up with the solution. Where I have left the mistake? If my answer is correct, what is its significance of it? I mean what are some interesting conclusions we can get from it?

(Please don't mind if I did anything terribly wrong. I am new to this and I'm not that strong in maths. If I have any mistakes please point that out. Thanks!)

Comment: Overall I am asking what is the speed of the image when seen through a convex lens. Explaining that would do. Thanks!